# How to control ViewPager with a fragment with SwipeRefreshLayout

Tags: android, fragment, swiperefreshlayout

In my app I use `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` with one `fragment` , I use it 3 times in the `adapter`. In my `Fragment` I have a `SwipeRefreshLayout` and a `Retrofit` . My problem is , When I swipe between pages and use the `SwipRefresh`, my content duplicated . How can I stop this duplication .

Thanks

```
swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            if (!isNetworkAvailable()) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No Internet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
                if (flag) {
                    listDataHeader.clear();
                    adapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(getActivity(), listDataHeader, listDataChild);
                    expListView.setAdapter(adapter);
                    getData();
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else {
                    listDataHeader.clear();
                    adapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(getActivity(), listDataHeader, listDataChild);
                    expListView.setAdapter(adapter);
                    getData();
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                }

            }, 4000);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Clear your arraylist every time you swap or SwipRefresh

Comment: show the code where you are updating your data after `SwipeRefreshLayout `

Comment: @AbdulKawee Please explain more because I didn't get what you say

Comment: @matinsayyad Where I can clear my list ?

Comment: @A.Elsayed you are calling some method `setOnRefreshListener()` somehwere in your code , need to see where you are updating list

Comment: @A.Elsayed Show us code

Comment: I put my SwipRefrsh code .

Comment: getData() is a function which contain Retrofit code .

Comment: @matinsayyad I put my code

Comment: @AbdulKawee I put my code

Comment: in onRefresh clear arraylist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you get data using  this getData(); that time arraylist or list will clear then fresh response bind into list or arraylist.